# Get record count using restforce

Tags: rest-api, collection, reports-api, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm running this query with `restforce` gem:

```
SCHEDULER.every '2m' do |job|

synergy = results

results = client.query("SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity Where Type='New Business'")
  send_event('synergy', { value: results })
end
```

I am getting this result when i run the query: `Restforce::Collection:0x007fb15c292010`

How can I get the record count instead of this result?

Comment: Are you missing a closing `"` on the SOQL statement?

Comment: @DanielBallinger made a mistake in copying the query here. Gives the same error.

Comment: when u run aggregation queries, u shd get back JSON representation of AggregateResult type something similar to https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce/blob/66ef4acdd0517e7b31a4105af242c1948723157f/spec/fixtures/sobject/query_aggregate_success_response.json and you can parse the desired value from there..

Comment: Something you should know about SOQL.  If you do `SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity...` you will get what is considered an aggregate query.  The result will look something like this `[{"attributes":{"type":"AggregateResult"},"expr0":1}]` in JSON.  However you can do `SELECT Count() FROM Opportunity...`  which will ONLY return a number.  You will still have to deal with the Restforce::Collection that @lsdr mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Restforce::Collection` is the *object* the `restforce` gem wraps the result of your `query()` API call around. And it is *always* a *collection*, which means that even a `COUNT` query will be wrap around something that resembles an `Array`.

In order to get the result you want, you have to take the first (and only) record from this *collection* and look for `expr0`, which is where the `COUNT` result will be stored:

```
results = client.query("SELECT Count(Id) FROM Opportunity Where Type='New Business'")

results.entries
=> [ 
  {
     "attributes" => {
     "type" => "AggregateResult"
  },
     "expr0" => 68
  }
]

results.first
=> {
   "attributes" => {
   "type" => "AggregateResult"
},
   "expr0" => 68
}

results.first["expr0"]
=> 68
```

Newer versions of `restforce` uses [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) to make it easier to access data from the JSON response:

```
results.first.expr0
=> 68
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Ruby or the restforce gem to speak adequately to this, but maybe you could also include what the result would look like for a non-aggregate query.  eg. `SELECT Count() FROM Opportunity WHERE Type = "New Business'`?

Comment: @DougB it returns a `Restforce::Collection` as result, but `results.first` would be `nil` and `results.entries` (list all items in the _collection_) is just an empty Array.